# Can you create multiple services from one factory in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service called tableService created using the code as follows:

```
app.factory('tableService', [function() {
   var data = some data;

   var foo = function (){
      //do something to data here
   };

   return {
      data: data,
      foo: foo
   }
}]);
```

I want to create another service that has the same properties as tableService so that I can use its functionality on a different set of data.

Is there anyway I can do something like

```
app.factory('tableService', 'secondService', [function() {


}]);
```

So that I don't have to repeat the code twice, one for each service?

Comment: something different to other set of data? why cant u use the same service twice?

Comment: the data in tableService is the same data that is used in one of my views

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use, a local object definition, create new instance from it by using a `getInstance` method.

```
 app.factory('tableService', [function() {
   var data = some data;

   MyService(){
       // code ...
       this.data = data;
   }

   MyService.prototype.foo = function(){
       // code ...
   }


   function getInstance(){
       return new MyService();
   }


   return {
      getInstance: getInstance,
   }
}]);
```

Creating instances :

```
var tableSericeA = tableService.getInstance();
var tableSericeB = tableService.getInstance();
```

Comment: what would go inside MyService(){} ?

Comment: It is a constructor function you, so, you can construct in it : this.data = data;